# External authentication for Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Is it possible to use Spring OAuth2 as a pure authorization solution while providing external authentication for it? Or is Spring OAuth2 even supposed to be used in such a manner? If yes then what are the injection points for that kind of configuration?

If your are familiar with [Kong](https://getkong.org/) then it's basically how the OAuth plugin works:

[image]

here Login Webapp (which is responsible for authentication) is an external application to Kong OAuth.